# Disable Filtered/Unfiltered and Toggle Filter Buttons in MS Access

Tags: vba, sorting, filter

In MS Access, I have two forms (running off one table) that has a pre-defined on-load filter for each.
My end-user likes to click the Toggle Filter or Filtered button as a means to clear any filters they've used within the form's table. This effectively brings records from the other form into the form they're working on.

I want to be able to disable these two buttons whilst still giving them the ability to use the sort/filter within the form's table's drop-down arrows.

How would this be achieved?

I have already tried using:

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)
  Cancel = ApplyType = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bind those forms not to the table directly, but each to a separate query, which only provides the desired records.

- `MyQuery1` for form 1:

  `Select * From MyTable Where MyField = '1'`
- `MyQuery2` for form 2:

  `Select * From MyTable Where MyField = '2'`

In each forms `Record Source` property do not reference the table `MyTable` but the desired query `MyQuery1` or `MyQuery2`.

Alternatively you can directly enter the shown sql statements into the forms `Record Source` properties.

So your users can filter as they want but never get 'unallowed' data, because the forms record source doesn't contain that data at all.

Comment: That's true, I was hoping we don't need to go down that path.

Comment: We are having a discussion when the end-users come back from their break.
But in the meantime, is there a VBA solution for the issue above?